# Drop tables that are not in a list?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-drop

I need to drop about 20k tables.  I know the names of the tables that are NOT to be dropped.

If I have table names "a,b,c,d,e,f,g...", how can I drop all tables that are not in the list "a,b,c"?

Comment: pray tell, 20k tables how did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get a resultset of SQL DROP statements:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', TABLE_NAME , ';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase'
AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN ('Table1', 'Table2');
```

Copy and paste the results, and you've got 20,000-*n* DROP statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list with this

```
SELECT CONCAT("DROP TABLE ", table_name, ";") 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = <whatever your db name is> 
AND table_name NOT IN (<your list>);
```

Then copy and paste!

Answer (score 2):

You need to run select from information_schema.tables and create a cursor that will iterate through the results and perform the appropriate drops (use if statement). This is because drop statement does not support selecting/filtering or other options. (unless something has changed during the last two or three years)

When you're performing the select statement you can use something like:

```
WHERE table_name NOT IN ('ssss','dddd');
```

Another thing is: why do you have 20k tables in your database?????

Comment: I know now - you have lots of similar tables separated by client. It makes everything easier and all the security audit people much happier.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you take the following approach

- extract a full list of all of the tables one table per line with `SHOW TABLES` (or from `information_schema.TABLES`)
- open the list in a text editor
- remove the tables that you don't want to remove from the list
- use a macro or search/replace to turn each line into a `DROP TABLE` command

Now you have an SQL script that you can run against the database

If you're a linux shell ninja might want to use commandline tools like `uniq`, `xargs`, etc to manipulate the files. Using a spreadsheet might be another way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a completely different approach if you can get away with the tables that you want to keep being made unavailable for a short period of time.

- Backup the tables that you want to keep
- `DROP DATABASE` the database with all of the tables in
- Restore the tables that you want to keep from the backups

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same problem today.  Here is one approach for skipping tables ABC, DEF and XYZ:

```
mysql -Nu USER --password=PASSWORD DATABASE -e 'show tables' | \
perl -ne 'BEGIN { print "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;\n" };
    !/^(ABC|DEF|XYZ)$/ && s/^(.*)/DROP TABLE `\1`;/ && print' | \
mysql -u USER --password=PASSWORD DATABASE
```

So what the devil is all that?

1. The first mysql call gets all the tables without the header row (-N option)
2. The output of mysql is piped to Perl
3. The Perl script adds a first line to skip foreign key checks since we are dropping the tables
4. The script then adds DROP TABLE X for each table, skipping the tables ABC, DEF and XYZ
5. The output from Perl goes to mysql, modifying the same database

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way. In one line, on your command line type:

```
mysql -u root -p[password] --skip-column-names [database] -e "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='[database]' AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN ('[table 1]', '[table 2]',..'[table n]');" | cut -f1 | sed -r 's/(.*)/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \1;/' | mysql -u root -p[password] [database]
```

You may get two warnings about including passwords in a command. If this may be a problem, you can clear the command history to 'remove the evidence' :-)

```
history -c
```